# Chewing Nicorette Gum for only 30 min

Tags: nicotine, chew-chewing

In the directions, it says to chew the nicorrette gum for only 30 min. I find that I can chew it for more than an hour before all the nicotine is gone. Is there a health reason why the company limits the time to 30 mins?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about the 30 mins duration you mentioned in your question, but I presume it has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

From [Nicorette.com](https://www.nicorette.com/products/nicorette-gum.html), the below shows its instructions.

Nicorette gum comes in two strengths - 2mg and 4mg. The following shows which one to use.

**2 MG**

If you smoke your first cigarette more than 30 minutes after waking up, use the 2 mg strength.

**4 MG**

If you smoke your first cigarette within 30 minutes of waking up, use the 4 mg strength.

**HOW TO USE NICORETTE GUM**

Just like any medicine, for Nicorette to do its job, you need to use it properly. Once you’ve chosen a quit date, start using Nicorette Gum on your quit date. Follow the directions on the label. To improve your chances of success, be sure to use at least 9 pieces of Nicorette a day for the first six weeks of your quit. Don’t eat or drink 15 minutes before or while you’re chewing Nicorette. Stay with the full 12 week quit program to increase your chances of success. However, if you find that you need to use Nicorette longer than 12 weeks, the FDA has determined that is acceptable to do so in most cases. Talk to your doctor or health care provider if you feel the need to use Nicorette for longer than 12 weeks.

If you are using Nicorette while trying to quit smoking but slip up and have a cigarette, you should not stop using Nicorette. You should keep using it and keep trying to quit.

For other questions you may have on the nicorette gum, visit [Nicorette's FAQs](https://www.nicorette.com/faq.html#accordion-content-5)

Comment: there's really nothing here about chewing for 30 minutes vs half an hour. How is this supposed to help the asker?

Comment: That's because the 30 mins duration has been removed, so chewing for more than 30 mins is okay.

Comment: Okay. So the company changed the directions I guess.

Comment: That's correct.